# Doubt about Sobolev space norm

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I consider the space $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. I have a function and I have to verify that it belongs to this space. In the text I'm reading the author verifies that the function and its Laplacian are in $L^2$, not considering the firs order derivatives.
So I remember that in $H^2$ I can consider the norm
$$\Vert u\Vert=(\Vert u\Vert^2_{L^2}+\Vert\Delta u\Vert_{L^2}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Is this norm equivalent to the usual norm
$$\Vert u\Vert=\bigg(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq2}\Vert D^\alpha u\Vert^2_{L^2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$?
If it is I understand the reasoning in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step you are missing is a so-called elliptic estimate for the laplacian, namely:

$$||u||_{H^2(\mathbb R^3)} \leq C(||\Delta u||_{L^2(\mathbb R^3)} + ||u||_{L^2(\mathbb R^3)}).$$

The proof is in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book for instance, and many other textbooks.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the reason why I can no consider the firast order derivative.